# Avoid page refresh when clicking on LinkButton in grid

Tags: c#, html

I have a `GridView` control, and inside of this control I have defined a link button using `GridView.ItemTemplate`.

I am using this to open a new window on click. When I click on the link button, however, the page refreshes before opening the new window.

How can I stop the page from refreshing after the link button is clicked?

Pop up is not displaying when i add Update panel to first grid

if i remove Update panel from first grid, grid is refreshing and popup is displaying

I need to open a popup without refreshing my grid

PLEASE FIND ME THE SOLUTION FOR THIS AS I WAS WORKING ON THIS FROM PAST 2 DAYS

**HTML**

```
<%@ Page Language="c#" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="ViewData1.aspx.cs" Inherits="ablesas.ViewDataUI1" EnableEventValidation="false"%>


            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel4" runat="server">
                        <ContentTemplate>

                                         <asp:GridView ID="DataGrid1"  style="visibility:visible" runat="server" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="#E9EDF5"  Font-Names="Arial"
                                                ForeColor="#09538A" Font-Size="12px" BackColor="#ffffff" BorderColor="DarkGray" Font-Bold="true" 
                                                HeaderStyle-BackColor="#298DC7" EnableViewState="false"  CellSpacing="20" 
                                                CellPadding="10"  HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowCommand="DataGrid1__RowCommand" OnRowDataBound="DataGrid1__RowDataBound" >
                                                <HeaderStyle Font-Names="Arial;" CssClass="MyHeaderStyle" Font-Size="13px" ForeColor="White" Font-Bold="True" Height="20"  BackColor="#298DC7" ></HeaderStyle>
        <asp:templatefield headertext="NDC" ItemStyle-CssClass="col" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Justify" HeaderStyle-Width="10%" ItemStyle-Width="10%">                                     <Columns>               
                    <itemtemplate>
                    <asp:linkbutton id="productcode"   ForeColor="#09538A" runat="server"  text='<%#Eval("product code")%>'></asp:linkbutton>                               

                                                     </itemtemplate>
                                        </asp:templatefield>
                   </asp:GridView>
                                </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>


                                        <AjaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1"   BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" CancelControlID="cancel" TargetControlID="Button3" runat="server" PopupControlID="pnlpopup"> </AjaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>
    <asp:Panel id="Panel1"  runat="server" Height="30px" Width="600px">
    </asp:Panel>        
                   <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" style="visibility:hidden" Text="Button" />
                            <asp:Panel ID="pnlpopup" CssClass="PanelPopup"  runat="server">
                                        <div  style="width:inherit;text-align:center;">Products of <%=ndc %> Product Family</div>
                                        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1"  runat="server" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="#f1f4f8"  Width="980px" Font-Names="Arial"
                                            Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#09538A" Font-Size="13px" BackColor="#ffffff" BorderColor="DarkGray"
                                            HeaderStyle-BackColor="#99cccc" EnableViewState="false"  CellSpacing="0" style="padding:10px;"
                                            CellPadding="3" ShowFooter="false" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowDataBound="productInfo_RowDataBound" >
                                            <HeaderStyle Height="10%" CssClass="MyHeaderStyle" Font-Size="13px" ForeColor="#FFFFFF" Font-Bold="true"  BackColor="#298DC7"></HeaderStyle>
                                            <rowstyle Height="20px" />
                        <alternatingrowstyle  Height="20px"/>
                                            <Columns>
                <asp:boundfield  datafield="product code" sortexpression="customers " ItemStyle-CssClass="col" headertext="NDC"/>

             <div id="div<%#  Convert.ToString(Eval("customer"))+ Convert.ToString(Eval("ManufacturingPartner"))+ Convert.ToString(Eval("product code"))+ Convert.ToString(Eval("Sales Person")) %>" style="display: none; position: relative; left: 15px; overflow: auto">
                                        <asp:GridView ID="gvOrderInfo" runat="server" ForeColor="#09538A"  AutoGenerateColumns="false" BorderStyle="Double"  BorderColor="#df5015"  Width="500px" OnRowDataBound="gvOrderInfo_RowDatabound">
                                        <HeaderStyle CssClass="MyHeaderStyle"  Font-Size="13px" ForeColor="#FFFFFF" Font-Bold="True"  BackColor="#298DC7"></HeaderStyle>
                                        <RowStyle BackColor="#E1E1E1" />
                                        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                                        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#df5015" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="White" />
                                        <Columns>
              <asp:BoundField DataField="Order Number" HeaderText="Order Number" ItemStyle-Width="75px" ItemStyle-CssClass="col" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                  </Columns>   
              </Columns>                            
                                        </asp:GridView>
                                    </div>                         
                                            </asp:GridView>
             </asp:Panel>
```

**Codebehind**

```
  protected void DataGrid1__RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {    
         this.UpdatePanel4.Update();
         if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
         {
              LinkButton lnk = e.Row.FindControl("productcode") as LinkButton;
              lnk.Click += new EventHandler(link_Click);

              //ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this).RegisterPostBackControl(lnk); 

              // string a = String.Format("0:N}",Convert.ToDecimal(e.Row.Cells[3].Text));
              if (e.Row.Cells[0].Text != "Total")
              {
                    //M1-Fmodification starts from here
                    if (ListBox2.Items.Count > 0)
                    //if (DataGrid1.Columns[0].Visible == true)
                    {
                    }              
              }
         }
    }
```

**Codebehind**

```
 public void productcode_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pnlpopup.Visible = true;
            //UpdatePanel3.Update();
            //this.UpdatePanel3.Update();
            GridViewRow clickedRow = ((LinkButton)sender).NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
            LinkButton lbtn = (LinkButton)clickedRow.FindControl("productcode");
            string customer = clickedRow.Cells[0].Text.ToString();
            string manufacturer = clickedRow.Cells[5].Text.ToString();
            string salesperson = clickedRow.Cells[6].Text.ToString();
            System.Data.DataTable newProductTable = null;
            ArrayList productDrilldownList = new ArrayList();
            productDrilldownList.Add(customer);
            productDrilldownList.Add(manufacturer);
            productDrilldownList.Add(lbtn.Text);
            productDrilldownList.Add(salesperson);


            try
            {
                ViewData1 vData = new ViewData1();
                DataSet ds1 = vData.__getProdOverviewDataSet(__getConnectionString());
                DataSet ds2 = vData.__getCustOverviewDataSet(__getConnectionString());
                DataSet ds3 = vData.__getSalesOverviewDataSet(__getConnectionString());
                DataSet ds4 = vData.__getManOverviewDataSet(__getConnectionString());
                DataSet ds5 = vData.__getBookedDateDataSet(__getConnectionString());

                List<DateTime> booked_date = new List<DateTime>();

                if (ds5.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (DataRow row in ds5.Tables[0].Rows)
                    {
                        if (row[0].ToString() != " " && row[0] != null)
                        {
                            booked_date.Add(Convert.ToDateTime(row[0]));
                        }
                    }
                }
                booked_date.Remove(Convert.ToDateTime("1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM"));
                booked_date.Sort();
                ArrayList daterange = new ArrayList();
                daterange = _getDateRange();
                if (Convert.ToDateTime(daterange[0]) > Convert.ToDateTime(daterange[1]))
                {
                 //   DataGrid1.Visible = false;
                 //   Label4.Visible = false;
                //    TxtCustProd.Visible = false;
                //    Panel1.Visible = false;
                //    ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "Javascript", "<script>alert('There is no data found')</script>");
                //    return;
                }
                if (ToDateTxtBox.Text != "" && ToDateTxtBox.Text != "To Date" && FromDateTxtBox.Text != "From Date")
                {
                    DropDownList2.Text = "Months";
                    DropDownList3.Text = "Years";
                    if (!booked_date.Contains(Convert.ToDateTime(daterange[2])) && !booked_date.Contains(Convert.ToDateTime(daterange[3])))
                    {
                     //   DataGrid1.Visible = false;
                     //   Label4.Visible = false;
                    //    TxtCustProd.Visible = false;
                    //    Panel1.Visible = false;
                    //    ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "Javascript", "<script>alert('There is no data found')</script>");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    ToDateTxtBox.Text = "";
                    FromDateTxtBox.Text = "";
                }




                int countCustomer = -1;
                int countProduct = -1;
                int countSales = -1;
                int countMan = -1;
                if (ds1.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    countProduct = ds1.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
                }
                if (ds2.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    countCustomer = ds2.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
                }
                if (ds3.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    countSales = ds3.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
                }
                if (ds4.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    countMan = ds4.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
                }


                System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
                string test = "";
                if(Session["callcount"] != null){
                    string coo = Session["callcount"].ToString(); 
                    int coi = Int16.Parse(coo);
                    Session["callcount"] = coi + 1;
                    test = Session["callcount"].ToString();
                }
                else{
                    int coi = 0;
                    Session["callcount"] = coi.ToString();
                    test = Session["callcount"].ToString();
                }
                dt = vData.__getProductLevelSource(__getConnectionString(), __getDropDownValues(), __getProdFilterValues(), __getCustFilterValues(), __getSalesFilterValues(), __getManFilterValues(), countCustomer, countProduct, countSales, countMan, _getDateRange(), __getProdFamilyFilterValues(), productDrilldownList);
                GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                GridView1.DataBind();
                //dt.Rows.Count
                Gridview_Columnshide(GridView1);
            }
            catch (Exception dateerr)
            {
                //DataGrid1.Visible = false;
                //Label4.Visible = false;
                //TxtCustProd.Visible = false;
                //Panel1.Visible = false;
                //ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "Javascript", "<script>alert('There is no data found')</script>");

            }

            ModalPopupExtender1.Show();
            //UpdatePanel3.Update();

        }
```

Comment: What you want to do when link button is clicked?

Comment: i want to show a popup which was defined above in code in that popup ineed to show another grid with values selected from parent grid

Comment: use Triggers in update panel it will help you

Comment: after adding update panel to gris it is not refreshing but popup panel is not opening

Comment: Show us code to open popup

Comment: which id i need to give in triggers whether gridID or linkID

Comment: thanks for the quick reply i have posted the code of link click there i was showing popup in last line of code

Comment: but popup is not diaplaying when i add update panel to grid

Comment: IF I REMOVE UPDATEPANEL FORM GRID POPUP IS DISPLAYING BUT GRID IS REFRESHING. i NEED TO AVOID REFRESH THE GRID. HOPE YOU UNDERSTAND MY PROBLEM

Comment: will u please provide me the solution in deatil by code so that i can fix my problem. as i do not know the javascript much. Please provide me the solution in detail.

Comment: @user2181338 But why you don't want a page refresh when it seems you are doing some server side logic on the button click?

Comment: con't we avoid refreshing page in doing server side logic on button click?

Answer (score 2):

Please try to add the model pop up extender inside the update panel.then it will pop up with out page refreshing.this is a sample code. this one is working without any problem. just check it one more time

```
  <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>



        <asp:GridView ID="DataGrid1" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="DataGrid1__RowDataBound">

            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="Value" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="NDC" ItemStyle-CssClass="col" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Justify" HeaderStyle-Width="10%" ItemStyle-Width="10%">

                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="productcode" ForeColor="#09538A" runat="server" Text='click'></asp:LinkButton>

                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>



        <AjaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" TargetControlID="Button3" runat="server" PopupControlID="pnlpopup"></AjaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>

        <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Style="visibility: hidden" Text="Button" />
        <asp:Panel ID="pnlpopup" CssClass="model-bd" runat="server">
            <input type="button" value="ok">
        </asp:Panel>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

----------C#------------

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("ID");
        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        DataRow dr1 = dt.NewRow();
        dr["ID"] = 1;
        dr1["ID"] =21;
        DataGrid1.DataSource = dt;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        dt.Rows.Add(dr1);
        DataGrid1.DataBind();
    }
    protected void DataGrid1__RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            LinkButton lnk = e.Row.FindControl("productcode") as LinkButton;
            lnk.Click += new EventHandler(productcode_Click);


        }
    }
     void productcode_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pnlpopup.Visible = true;



        ModalPopupExtender1.Show();


    }
```

Comment: Getting Error : An extender can't be in a different UpdatePanel than the control it extends.

Comment: @user2181338 put button3 and model pop extender & panel in same updatepanel.

Comment: Getting Error: Error 65 Type 'System.Web.UI.UpdatePanel' does not have a public property named 'Panel'. and 'button'

Comment: what i meant is <updatepanel><ContentTemplate>place your grid, button,panel,model pop up extender</ContentTemplate></updatepanel>

Comment: yeh i have tried this but same problem pop up is not showing on click of link button in first grid

Comment: Is there any other solution with u?

Comment: check the updated code. it is a working code. i tested now.it working properly.so please refer this one.

Comment: if it is solve your problem, please accept the answer. so it will useful to others

Comment: i have tried it again same problem is hapening popup is not opening

Comment: Or please tell me how to use hyperlink instead of link button from above code because link button is server side control it will do postback but hyperlink will wont do

Comment: i have tried your solution but on clcik of link button popup is not opening

Comment: i fit debug the code is hitting the click events but popup is not opening